# Make php variable, and change/get in another 2 php file

Tags: php

In x.php :

```
$string = "";
```

In y.php :

```
include 'x.php';
$string = "max";
```

In z.php :

```
include 'x.php';
$s = $string;
echo $s;
```

At the start in the x.php : `$string = ""`

After the y.php : `$string = "max"` in the x.php

After the z.php : `$s = "max"`

How can i do this? (The y.php and z.php must be separate.)

Answer (score 2):

Just include `y.php` in `z.php` (And remove the include in `y.php`), but after you included `x.php` to get your logic.

You can think of include as if it just would place the code there, so `z.php` would end up like this:

```
include 'x.php';
include 'y.php';
$s = $string;
echo $s;
```

After the includes:

```
$string = "";
$string = "max";
$s = $string;
echo $s;
```

OR if you want you can include `x.php` into `y.php` and `y.php` into `z.php`, but then I would recommend you to use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), so that your paths doesn't get messed up, e.g.

x.php:

```
$string = "";
```

y.php:

```
include __DIR__ . "/x.php";
$string = "max";
```

z.php:

```
include __DIR__ . "/y.php";
$s = $string;
echo $s;
```

**EDIT:**

As from your update:

> *(The y.php and z.php must be separate.)*

This will not work! How should you be able to assign `max` to `$s` if they never *somehow* gets included?!

Comment: @Dreamfire Then your code will not work! Then your code logic is wrong! How should `max` gets assigned to `$s` if you never somehow include `y.php` into `z.php` that simply does not work

Comment: Ok not work. But i cant do NOTHING to make this somehow, with function or object php or another ? nothing ?

Comment: @Dreamfire No, I think your problem is in your code logic! I mean if you now include the code from y into x and then x into z you will end up as if you just include x and y into z